# transform of predictor variables

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references

Assume I have a linear model like this:

$$
y_i = \beta_1 x_{i1} + \cdots + \beta_{ip} x_{ip} + \varepsilon_i \hspace{1cm} i = 1,\dots,n
$$

I know that if $y_i$ must be greater than zero, I should fit against $\log(y_i)$ rather than $y_i$. If $y_i$ must be between $[0,1]$ (like the case in logistic regression), I should use a logistic link function.

On the other hand, from my experience, I found that if $x_{ij}$ must be greater than zero. Usually I will get a better fit if I first log-transform it, i.e. I use $\log(x_{ij})$ rather than $x_{ij}$.

Are there any theory for this experience?

Moreover, Let's say:

(1) If I know $x_{ij}$ is an indicator variable (must be either $0$ or $1$). Shall I use an inverse of logistic function to transform it first?

(2) How about if I know $x_{ij}$ is on the interval $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular need for the independent variables (or, for that matter, the dependent variable) to be in any particular range or have any particular distribution. Assumptions are made about the distribution of the *errors* which are estimated by the residuals.

When the DV *has to be* in a specified range, transformations can be useful.  But the IVs don't get predicted; they are what they are.

I would transform them only if there was substantive reason to do so. E.g. a log transform of income is often useful, not just because income is skewed but because it changes multiplication to addition - that is, the change from 20,000 to 40,000 becomes similar to that between 40,000 and 80,000 rather than 40,000 and 60,000.